# A smart Ox to solve math problems.

Tags: probability, statistics

Found an interesting 1907 article and am curious about how and why the underlying math works.

> On a livestock fair in late Victorian Plymouth, England, a
> statistician with the name of Francis Galton asked around 800
> attendees to guess the weight of an ox that was on display. He then
> calculated the mean of all estimates, which ended up being 1208
> pounds[¹](https://www.nature.com/articles/075450a0.pdf). To his surprise, the measured weight of said ox was 1197
> pounds, which put the mean estimation at ~0.01% off from the real
> weight.

[image: ox]

Are similar "herd" concepts applicable to solve other math problems? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds would be a good place to start in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major factor here is that most people either guess too high or too low, so if you average them they'll cancel each other out. This is reproducible at a large scale. The specific case cited here is probably just one time it happened to be really close, and if it was done again it probably wouldn't work (The media has a knack for these things, ignoring the mass results and only looking at specific cases that are "impressive"), but if you use this method of estimation you'll get pretty good results.